# textField returning Decimal for Calculation

Tags: decimal, textfield, calculator

I have a textfield called stateTextField.  The purpose of this textField is for the user to enter in their state's abbreviation.  (example: PA, CA, NH, ME)

When they type in the abbreviation, I want my app to realize it and assign it a decimal number for state income tax calculation purposes.

so this is what I have so far:

```
 float netPay = grossPay * taxRate;
 float stateTax = grossPay * stateRate;
 float netPayState = netPay - stateTax;
 float stateRate = [stateTextField.text floatValue];
    if ([stateTextField.text isEqualToString:@"PA"] ||
        [stateTextField.text isEqualToString:@".9693"])
```

However, I don't think this is going to work, am I going about this right?  Please be polite, I am learning Objective C and this is new to me.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with trial and error:

```
float PA = .0307;
float PATax = grossPay * PA;
if([self.stateTextField.text  isEqual: @"PA"]) {
    netPay = (grossPay - bonusRate) * taxRate - twoTaxes - PATax;
```